# Which Pokémon of the first generation is the most resistant to all types?

Tags: pokemon-go

With all those people playing Pokémon GO nowadays I was wondering which Pokémon of the first generation is the most resistant to all types?

Comment: Are you talking about pokemon-go, the series(handheld games) or the series(tv)?

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck, as the Pokémon with the most resistances overall also happens to be a first gen Pokémon. The Magnemite evolutionary line boasts 11 resistances and 1 full immunity.

Comment: Wasn't Magnemite in the original generation a purely electric pokemon like Pikachu, instead of electric-steel?

Comment: @Nzall Correct, but that's not the case in Pokémon Go. The game uses sixth gen typings.

Comment: I see. I thought they were talking about the first generation games and that Pokémon Go was the incentive to ask about it.

Comment: @Baklap4 The very first Pokémon in the Pokédex was dual typed so I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: I was going to say, I'm relatively sure that Bulbasaur is Grass/Poison.

Comment: Guess you're right @Kaizerwolf http://imgur.com/5wBHATH

Comment: The thing is, depending on the games themselves (red/blue vs. yellow), the typings and advantages were different. In Yellow, for example, Psychic was insane, because it's only weakness was Bug, and the only Bug pokemon with a threatening move to Psychic types had a poison subtype as well, making Psychic almost unstoppable.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The typing issues were the same across all gen 1 games. Game Freak only changed the type chart a generation later.

Comment: Oh no kidding.. I've only played through Yellow, I had always heard that Yellow was the worst. I didn't know it was all of Gen 1, thanks!

Comment: Fun Fact: It's actually 11 resistances and 1 immunity

Comment: So... what you're saying is I need to find a place where Magnemites spawn. Right?

Comment: @Ellesedil Depends. If you want one, then yes.

Comment: Considering a lot of the gyms I see hold water and flying types, and Magnemites are so resistant to a lot of things, then I'm pretty sure I want one.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of pure Gen 1, in a world where Steel, Dark & Fairy don't exist, and where Bug and Poison were super effective against each other for some reason, the most resistances any Pokemon had was 6. And the winners are:

Dragonite (Dragon/Flying) - 5 Resistances + 1 Immunity to Ground
Aerodactyl (Rock/Flying) - 5 Resistances + 1 Immunity to Ground
Rhydon / Golem / Onix (Rock/Ground) - 5 Resistances + 1 Immunity to Electric.

If you want to go a step further and take Dragonite out of the equation, only Aerodactyl and the Rock/Ground types have 4 Resistances, 1 Strong Resistance (1/4 Effectiveness) and 1 Immunity each.

Since Gen II and the introduction of Steel, Magnemite/Magneton, and as of Gen IV, Magnezone are the only Electric/Steel types, and as such are the only ones that have 9 Resistances, 2 Strong Resistances and 1 Immunity.

And, since Pokemon GO uses the Gen VI type chart with Gen I Pokemon, Magneton reigns supreme in the type department.

Answer (score 1):

Magnemite and Magneton are the ones with the highest number of resistances, being 11: Normal, Grass, Electric, Bug, Flying, Poison, Rock, Ice, Psychic, Dragon, and Steel.